# LibGDX Issue with spawnTime Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, google-play

I'm trying to make the obstacles re-generate themselves in this game I'm almost finishing to create, However, Android Studio complains with a series of new errors :

```
Error:(133, 4) Gradle: error: illegal start of expression
Error:(133, 12) Gradle: error: illegal start of expression
Error:(133, 28) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(136, 19) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(170, 22) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(170, 34) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(184, 23) Gradle: error: ';' expected
Error:(188, 1) Gradle: error: reached end of file while parsing
```

Should I create a SpawnEntity class? Here's the code for my MainGame class:

```
package com.circlecrashavoider;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactImpulse;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Manifold;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;
import com.circlecrashavoider.entities.FloorEntity;
import com.circlecrashavoider.entities.ObstacleEntity;
import com.circlecrashavoider.entities.ObstacleEntity2;
import com.circlecrashavoider.entities.PlayerEntity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created by Felipe on 2/22/2016.
 */

public class GameScreen extends BaseScreen {

    private Stage stage;

    private World world;

    private PlayerEntity player;

    private List<FloorEntity> floorList = new ArrayList<FloorEntity>();

    private List<ObstacleEntity> obstacleList = new ArrayList<ObstacleEntity>();

    private List<ObstacleEntity2> obstacle2List = new ArrayList<ObstacleEntity2>();

    public GameScreen(MainGame game) {
        super(game);
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(1024, 620));
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);


        world.setContactListener(new ContactListener() {

            private boolean areCollided(Contact contact, Object userA, Object userB) {
                return (contact.getFixtureA().getUserData().equals(userA) && contact.getFixtureB().getUserData().equals(userB)) ||
                        (contact.getFixtureA().getUserData().equals(userB) && contact.getFixtureB().getUserData().equals(userA));
            }

            @Override
            public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
                if (areCollided(contact, "player", "floor")) {
                    player.setJumping(false);
                    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                        player.setMustJump(true);
                    }
                }

                if (areCollided(contact, "player", "obstacle")) {
                    player.setAlive(false);
                    System.out.println("GAME OVER");

                }

                if (areCollided(contact, "player", "obstacle2")) {
                    player.setAlive(false);
                    System.out.println("GAME OVER");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void endContact(Contact contact) {

            }

            @Override
            public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) {

            }

            @Override
            public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        Texture playerTexture = game.getManager().get("player.png");
        Texture floorTexture = game.getManager().get("floor.png");
        Texture overfloorTexture = game.getManager().get("overfloor.png");
        Texture overfloor2Texture = game.getManager().get("overfloor2.png");
        Texture obstacleTexture = game.getManager().get("obstacle.png");
        Texture obstacle2Texture = game.getManager().get("obstacle2.png");


        player = new PlayerEntity(world, playerTexture, new Vector2(1, 2));


        for (FloorEntity floor : floorList) {

            stage.addActor(floor);
        }
        for (ObstacleEntity obstacle : obstacleList) {

            stage.addActor(obstacle);


            stage.addActor(player);
        }
        for (ObstacleEntity2 obstacle2 : obstacle2List) {
            stage.addActor(obstacle2);
        }

    }


    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        Texture playerTexture = game.getManager().get("player.png");
        Texture floorTexture = game.getManager().get("floor.png");
        Texture overfloorTexture = game.getManager().get("overfloor.png");
        Texture overfloor2Texture = game.getManager().get("overfloor2.png");
        Texture obstacleTexture = game.getManager().get("obstacle.png");
        Texture obstacle2Texture = game.getManager().get("obstacle2.png");

        float timer = 0;
        float spawnTime = 4f;
    private void spawnEntity();
    {
        //Increment timer by the duration since the previous frame
        float timer += Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
        //Compare to spawntime
        if (timer >= (float) spawnTime)
        {
            //Spawn your object
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 0, 1000, 1));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,8, 10 ,5));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,10, 10 ,8));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,34 , 3 ,5));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,19 , 8 ,4));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,24 , 8 ,1.5f));
            floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture ,27 , 5 , 2));
            obstacleList.add(new ObstacleEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture, overfloor2Texture ,25, 10 ,20));
            //But you will probably want to spawn something on the right, just outside of your screen view.

            //This is the right side of your vp in the world. Depending how you draw you can add some more to it.
            float spawnX = camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth / 2;
            //Then use this to spawn your object, since you hardcoded stuff I have no idea where to put it.

            //Now reset timer
            timer-= spawnTime;

            //And perhaps randomize the spawnTime? (between 2 and 4 seconds)
            Random random;
            spawnTime = random.nextFloat() * 2 + 2;
        }
    }






    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.6f, 1, 3f);
        Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);



        stage.act();
        world.step(delta, 6 ,2);
        stage.draw();
    }



    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        world.dispose();
    }
}
```

I don't have a SpawnEntity class, should I create it? What can I do to fix this problem? Please Help Me!!

Comment: Your `update` method is missing its closing bracket. When you see these errors, scroll through your file. Intellij highlights syntax errors like this with a squiggly red underline.

Comment: I notice many severe problems related to scope of variables. I think you need to read up on Java basics some or you're going to want to bang your head on the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues related to your code.

First, you are getting errors because you did not close your **update** function, you can't put a function inside another function, but you can call a function from another one, like so :

```
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    spawnEntity();
}
```

Another error that will occur is that you never created the Random object, so calling a method from it will result in a **`NullPointerException`**. To avoid this, you need to instantiate your Random object somewhere :

```
Random random = new Random();
// ...
spawnTime = random.nextFloat() * 2f + 2f;
```

Note that for performance reasons it's best not to instantiate it in your update loop, as it's called multiple times per seconds.

You can also simply use the LibGDX's method to achieve the same result :

```
spawnTime = MathUtils.random(2f, 4f);
```

Another error is that your FloorList will never add any floor entity because you always reset the timer to 0 **within the update method**, so they will most likely never reach 4. The proper way would be to set spawnTime as an attribute (with your stage, world, and player).

the fixed code could look like this :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;

// ... define your class ...

private float spawnTime = 4f;
private float timer = 0;

// ...


public void update(float deltaTime) {
    // Increment timer by the duration since the previous frame
    timer += deltaTime;

    if (timer >= spawnTime) {
        this.spawnEntity();

        // the next spawn time will be triggered between 2 and 4 seconds :
        spawnTime = MathUtils.random(2f, 4f); 
        timer = 0;
    }
}



private void spawnEntity() {
    Texture floorTexture = game.getManager().get("floor.png");
    Texture overfloorTexture = game.getManager().get("overfloor.png");
    Texture overfloor2Texture = game.getManager().get("overfloor2.png");

    //Spawn your object
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 0, 1000, 1));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 8, 10, 5));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 10, 10, 8));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 34, 3, 5));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 19, 8, 4));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 24, 8, 1.5f));
    floorList.add(new FloorEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture,overfloor2Texture, 27, 5, 2));
    obstacleList.add(new ObstacleEntity(world, floorTexture, overfloorTexture, overfloor2Texture, 25, 10 ,20));
}
```

As for your Class creation question, you can create a SpawnEntity class if you want but as you see, it's not required : that's up to you and how you want to manage your code. But that's certainly a wise choice as it will be easier to manage everything when your code grows.